# Finding last and previous values in the group with fast MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I can get the results that I need, but I need a fast query.

```
id      value1      fid
1000    1203        5
1001    1293        1
1002    1203        3
1003    1211        1
1004    1263        1
1005    1223        5
1006    1243        2
1007    123         5
1008    1049        2
1009    1205        3
```

Here are the results that I need:

```
fid id      value1      id2     previous_value1
1   1004    1263        1003    1211
2   1008    1049        1006    1243
3   1009    1205        1002    1203
5   1007    123         1005    1223
```

Any ideas?

---

Edit: I forgot to wrote my query here is my query:

```
SELECT
t1.fid,
t1.id,
t1.value1,
t2.id AS id2,
t2.value1 AS previous_value1
FROM
(
  SELECT
  MAX(id) AS id
  FROM TABLENAME
  GROUP BY fid
) t3
INNER JOIN TABLENAME t1 ON t1.id = t3.id
INNER JOIN TABLENAME t2 ON t2.id = (SELECT id FROM TABLENAME WHERE id < t1.id AND fid =     t1.fid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Actually I simplified it by removing extra columns.

(There is 2 more columns in WHERE statement but it doesn't matters.)

The original query takes ~0.04seconds.  If I filter the results with the other two columns in where statement, it takes ~0.001 seconds.

Comment: is this some sort of Mensa puzzle to guess the question?

Comment: @Jet Php the question, as written, very much comes off as "I figured it out, now let's see if you can", which I'm sure isn't the tone you're looking for. It would be helpful to show us your solution, and let us suggest improvements to *it*. Thanks. :)

Comment: I don't think MySQL supports windowing yet. Too bad for this query.

Comment: @djacobson Sorry, I forgot to wrote my own query. But it is clear that I use grouping and comparing ids. I want to know if there is another advanced approach. Why would I ask if you can if I found the advanced way. This is not a competition site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is a query that returns what you want (at least, what I think you want), but its anything but fast and efficient, so try it first:

```
SELECT  A.*, 
        (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM YourTable WHERE fid = A.fid AND id < B.MaxId ORDER BY id DESC) Id2,
        (SELECT TOP 1 value1 FROM YourTable WHERE fid = A.fid AND id < B.MaxId ORDER BY id DESC) previous_value1
FROM YourTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT fid, MAX(id) Maxid
            FROM YourTable 
            GROUP BY fid) B
ON A.id = B.Maxid
ORDER BY A.fid
```

Comment: Hi Lamak, Thanks for your response. I use similar query to your suggestion but I want to know if there is a fast technique.

Comment: I end up duplicating table. I hold max 10 rows per group by deleting when it exceeds. Doing that I guarantee speed when the original table grows since I don't need old records for that module.